# pytest: fixtures as function arguments

Tags: python, pytest

As its [document](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixtures-as-function-arguments) says, pytest accepts fixtures as function arguments. However, this somewhat contradicts the convention in almost all languages that parameter names shouldn't affect a function's behavior. For example:

This works:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def name():
    return 'foo'

def test_me(name):
    assert name == 'foo'
```

But this doesn't:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def name():
    return 'foo'

def test_me(nam):
    assert nam == 'foo'
```

I think there must be some introspection here which requires testing function parameters to be valid fixtures. Am I correct on this?

---

Besides fixtures, there are other *magic* parameter names that confused me. One of them is `request`:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=['foo', 'bar'])
def name(request):
    return request.param

def test_me(name):
    assert name == 'foo'
```

Without reading its doc, it might seem you can rename `request` to another name such as `req`:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=['foo', 'bar'])
def name(req):
    return req.param

def test_me(name):
    assert name == 'foo'
```

But then running the test will complain fixture `req` not found. It further confused me because the listed available fixtures didn't include `request`. I'm not sure it's proper to call `request` a fixture here, but the error message is contradicting itself:

> E  fixture 'req' not found
>
> > available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, name, pytestconfig, record_xml_attribute, record_xml_property, recwarn, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory, worker_id
>
> > use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.

So how many *magic names* like this I must take care of when using pytest to not get into a pitfall?

Comment: for the second code snippet, you have to send the function (in which you used fixture decorator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, Py.test injects a little bit of argument-name introspection magic to keep your test cases concise.

Aside from any fixtures you have available (as you found out with `pytest --fixtures`), I do think `request` is the only additional magic parameter (unless, of course, you use, say, `@pytest.mark.parametrize('foo', (...))`, in which case `foo` is a magic parameter for that marked test case or fixture, etc.).

As an aside, I think it's best not to think about Py.test `test_` functions as regular old functions anyway, as they're not directly called as such by Py.test.